# Selecting Treeview node form CodedUI

Tags: c#, treeview, devexpress, coded-ui-tests

The tree view structure is created in Devexpress 8.3 and added to the windows form application which is written in VS2005. I have recorded a VS 2010 coded UI test case and trying to access that tree structure in the that. I am not able to access the tree structure. It throwing exception : cannot perform a click on hidden component.

Please suggest how to access the tree view node from codedUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, it is impossible with DX v8.3, because [Coded UI Test Extension for DevExpress WinForms](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Coded-UI/) controls was introduced only [in v12.1](https://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/WhatsNew2012v1/?page=42) and above. Thus you should upgrade to the latest version of DevExpress controls...

Comment: Thank you so much. Any suggestions like which tool i can use for this type of scenario...?